# Dompdf page_script() show footer in selected sections of PDF - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

Hello I need help with a pdf that I am generating with laravel

I have
this function in my controller

```
$all_view = $view1.'<br>'. $view2.'<br>'. $view3.'<br>'. $view4.'<br>'. $view5.'<br>'. $view6.'<br>'. $view7.'<br>'. $view8.'<br>'. $view9.'<br>'. $view10.'<br>'. $view11.'<br>'. $view12.'<br>'. $view_img;
    $pdf->setPaper('letter');

    $pdf->loadHTML($all_view);
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

All this returns my complete pdf, each view variable returns a view that I send to call within the same controller with each section of the pdf

and i use this into body of $view1

```
<div id="footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 d-flex justify-content-start footer_interlineado">FDSDFSD43 Approved February 25, Revised 2015
                <br>
                Prepared by Crower
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And i need this footer not show in $view_img I define it in the variable where I put together all the sections of the pdf

additional for the page I use this that I have it in the section inside the $ view1, that this if I need it in all the sections including $ view_img no problem

```
<script type="text/php">
if (isset($pdf)) {
    $text = "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
    $size = 8;
    $font = $fontMetrics->getFont("Times New Roman");
    $width = $fontMetrics->get_text_width($text, $font, $size) / 2;
    $x = $pdf->get_width() - 108;
    $y = $pdf->get_height() - 55;
    $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size);
}
```

I really appreciate who could help me

Comment: It is pretty difficult to understand your problem because of the language barrier. Can you please explain your problem a bit further with some image-examples how the pdf currently looks like and how you want it to look like? You can use deepl.com for a pretty good spanish <-> english translation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sorry about my English,  

    
I'll explain something simpler  
I have 3 views in blade.php  
view1.blade.php
view2.blade.php
view_img.blade.php
  
View_1 contains the start <html>.....<body>  

and ends with the view_img with </html> all that is concatenated  

It happens that I have a footer that repeats in all the pages and I need that footer not to be shown in the image_view

Comment: Can't you just add a parameter like $disable_footer=true to your view-loading and then show/hide the footer with a simple if?

Comment: the problem is that the footer is not handled by sections but *<div id="footer">* is only in view1 and automatically dompdf repeats it throughout the document